# How to print the fractional part of float number while converting to string

Tags: c++

I have a code which will  convert the float value to string, i have written like below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float myFloat= 10.80;
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << myFloat;
    cout<<"value = " << ss.str();
    std::string s(ss.str());
    cout<<"value = " << s;

    return 0;
}
```

But the problem is when my value is 10.66 its coming 10.66 but when its 10.80 its coming like 10.8 or when its 10.00 its coming 10 only .

How can i print the complete value

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"the complete value"*? Are you trying to print the literal value that you assigned to the float? Because the compiler makes no distinction between `10.80` and `10.8`. The value of the float is the same either way, and it retains no memory of how many trailing zeroes you had. If you want to make that distinction, then you'll want a string (*i.e. std::string value = "10.80"*), not a float. Or are you trying to specifically print 2 digits after the decimal point, regardless of how the float was initialized?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code .
 Use the **setprecision** function with '2' .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

float myFloat= 10.80;
stringstream stream;
stream << fixed << setprecision(2) << myFloat;
string s = stream.str();
cout<<"value = " << s;
       return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The trailing zeros are only kept if you set either fixed or scientific mode.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x  = 4.2;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the least complicated way would be to use printf instead of `std::cout.` There you can specifically specify how many digits are to be displayed.

```
#include "stdio.h"

printf("%3.2f",myfloat);
```

where 3 is the # of digits before and 2 the # of digits after the dot, either can be left out. Append '\n' to the string if you want a new line.

EDIT: Ok, I did not know about setprecision(2).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float myFloat= 10.80;
    std::ostringstream ss;
ss << fixed << setprecision(2) << myFloat;
    cout<<"value = " << ss.str();
std::string s(ss.str());
    cout<<"value = " << s;
}
```